# Invite facebook friends to our application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-invite

I'm using [facebook php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) and developing an application where in I wanna invite facebook friends for some `link` by sending message to them. So whoever I invited, I wanna save those facebook Ids into my database. Please suggest some solutions to send message to each `facebook friend` and get his `facebbokId`. The work is more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your using php sdk ...

By using the  below PHP code you can get the friends list from the facebook

```
                <?php
                $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                      'appId'  => 'CLIENT_ID',
                      'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
                ));          
                $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                $user = $facebook->getUser();
                $result =file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user.'/friends?access_token='.$access_token.'');  
                                    print_r($result);
                ?>
```

After getting the friends list data from the facebook by using sdk..If you want to store the details you store it into your database

Javascriptcode:

```
$.ajax({
                        type:'POST',                            
                        url:'/action_comes_here',
                        data:{},
                        success: function()
                        {
                            var user_ids = array('14545456','5695695456'); //
                            FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                                  app_id:'CLIENT_ID',
                                  message: 'TITLE',
                                  data:{},
                                  to: user_ids,   
                                },
                                function(response) { 
                                    if(response){
                                        ///SUCCESS HERE
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ///FALIURE COMES HERE
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                            alert("Something went wrong ... Please Try again");

                            }
                 });
```

Thanks
Sakthi